# Unable to show <br/> in <pre><code> tags posted from TinyMCE

Tags: html, tinymce

I am trying use TinyMCE to get code syntax to be displayed in the <pre><code> tag that will render highlighted syntax referencing css and javascript downloaded from https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js.

What I hope to achieve was to create a plugin to insert the <pre><code> tags to contain the codes user posts. While I manage to create the plugin, the <br/> tags was not represented after I have posted the codes. Meaning that the submitted codes are shown as a one-liner, which is not desirable.

What I'm trying to find out is how do I maintain the <br/> tags within the codes I have posted.

Using the Tinymce's default HTML code plugin, if I just simply encapsulate <pre><code> tags around the codes user posts, it also does not render the <br/> tag.

I would greatly appreciate any help or pointers to this issue. Many Thanks!

Comment: Inside a `<pre>` tag, line-breaks are treated literally, there's no need for `<br>`s in your code, just use line breaks normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trying to render the string `<br/>`, don't forget you need to encode it as `&lt;br/&gt;`

(Are there still people who write `<br/>` instead of just `<br>`? Wow.)